# Test-net recovery

Tags: blockchain, testnets, coinbase, recovery

Guys I send my token to the testnet address when I trying recover that on Coinbase wallet it’s telling me that I don’t have access to the right account, I can still recover my tokens or everything it’s gone ?
Thx.

Comment: If you have the private key for the testnet address you can import the account in a wallet that supports the blockchain you are using to send the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering tokens sent to a testnet address on Coinbase Wallet is unlikely.

Try using this tool from Coinbase: https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/sending-or-receiving-cryptocurrency/lost-assets

Comment: Yes I try that already, it’s telling me: Your account doesn’t have access to this transaction;(

Comment: Maybe bc I use Uniswap on Coinbase wallet, I’m very confused 